# Add myToken as payment and as pay to in smart contract

Tags: ether, dapps, tokens

Hi I have a token that I am trying to use as payment for a smart contract and to pay out. How can I do that in solidity where payment is not ether but rather my token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a smart contract to receive tokens and know that the tokens have been received, you need a two step process.

1. `myToken.approve(receivingContractAddress, numberOfTokens)`
2. `receivingContract.receive(numberOfTokens)`

   This function then calls `myToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, receivingContractAddress, numberOfTokens)` to receive the tokens from the sender.

This is the method used in the TokenTrader on https://cryptoderivatives.market where the TokenTrader contract can buy tokens using the following function from https://github.com/bokkypoobah/TokenTrader/blob/master/contracts/TokenTraderFactory.sol#L286-L321 :

```
// Taker sells asset tokens for ethers by:
// 1. Calling the asset's approve() method with the following parameters
//    _spender            is the address of this contract
//    _value              is the number of tokens to be sold
// 2. Calling this takerSellAsset() method with the following parameter
//    etherValueOfTokens  is the ether value of the asset tokens to be sold
//                        by the taker
//
// The TakerSoldAsset() event is logged with the following parameters
//   seller                  is the seller's address
//   amountOfTokensToSell    is the amount of the asset tokens being
//                           sold by the taker
//   tokensSold              is the number of the asset tokens sold
//   etherValueOfTokensSold  is the ether value of the asset tokens sold
//
// This method was called sell() in the old version
//
function takerSellAsset(uint256 amountOfTokensToSell) {
    if (buysTokens || msg.sender == owner) {
        // Maximum number of token the contract can buy
        // Note that buyPrice has already been validated as > 0
        uint256 can_buy = this.balance / buyPrice;
        // Token lots available
        // Note that units has already been validated as > 0
        uint256 order = amountOfTokensToSell / units;
        // Adjust order for funds available
        if (order > can_buy) order = can_buy;
        if (order > 0) {
            // Extract user tokens
            if (!ERC20(asset).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), order * units)) throw;
            // Pay user
            if (!msg.sender.send(order * buyPrice)) throw;
        }
        TakerSoldAsset(msg.sender, amountOfTokensToSell, order * units, order * buyPrice);
    }
}
```